# How to show progressbar until WP8 WebBrowser control loaded parameter?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a WebBrowser control and I want to show some url by parameter on this control. Until the webbrower loaded the page, I need to show some progressbar or animation.

Please help me, here's what I have:

```
 public partial class brw : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public brw()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        string parameterValue = NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter"];
        System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(parameterValue);
        webbrowser.Source = uri;

    }


    private void WebBrowser_Navigating_1(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        progressbar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void WebBrowser_Navigated_1(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        progressbar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_1(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {    
    }
```

}

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using `LoadCompleted` property.

XAML:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="progressbar" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="webbrw" IsScriptEnabled="True" LoadCompleted="yesLoaded"/>
```

.cs:

```
private void yesLoaded(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    this.progressbar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; 
    this.progressbar.IsIndeterminate = False;
}
```

Have a look at [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0524d6/web-browser-control-with-progress-bar-in-windows-phone-7/) sample.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
webbrowser.Navigate(new Uri(parameterValue));
```

instead of

```
webbrowser.Source = uri;
```

set Progressbar's Property `IsIndeterminate="True"`

```
<ProgressBar Foreground="Orange" x:Name="progressbar" Visibility="Collapsed" IsIndeterminate="True" Height="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" />
```